# Why I am not able to access event value in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, dom-events

I have been asked this question by someone. I was not able to give a correct answer. Could you please help me out? Why we can't access the value of event (e) in setTimeout?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    number: 1,
  }

  handleNumber = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(e) // It becomes null here.
      if(e) {
      this.setState({number: this.state.number + 1})
      console.log(this.state.number)
    }
  }, 10)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleNumber}>Hello world</button>
      </div>
)}
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: setTimeout((e) => {...}, 10) maybe passing e will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the event, more likely you're trying to access a property of the synthetic event like `e.type` or something like that. Because React reuses the synthetic event object, all properties of the event become null once the `handleNumber` function returns. See [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) for more info.

Comment: I've taken another look on this question, after reading in the docs I realized you are correct in this case. But it seems that all the properties are null, isn't it because of the context?

Comment: It's just how React handles events internally. When the event handler (`handleNumber`) returns, it mutates the event instance. So when the timeout fires, the properties are `null` instead of what they originally were.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I totally forgot to look into docs. Now it makes sense why I was not able to access event value in setTimeout. Thanks again.